# update in angular 4 and firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am working on Angular 4 project.
 I want to editthe form data using firebase key

I have pass the data through component.ts as follow

```
    this.service.editEnquiry(this.data);
```

I called `editEnquiry()` of service. the `editEnquiry()` is given as follows

```
editEnquiry(data)
{

    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.key);    
     this.af.list(`/enquirydata/`+key).update(data);
}
```

I am getting the data and firebase in `editEnquiry()`  but its not updating the record in firebase.
Its giving me following error

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

any help?

Comment: key is undefined. You probably want data.key.

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
this.af.object(`/enquirydata/`+ {key_of_entry_you_want_to_update}).update(data);
```

Comment: It showing me like this error  ':' expected.

Comment: should I pass only key or the whole row data